# Webview not showing content properly

Tags: android, webview

Im haveing small problem.
While i am trying to open a url inside webview the contents are not showing up.
if i try this on my computer it does work.

the result on my pc is like this(sorry for blurring, but you can still see that there are some text.) ;

[image]

and then my device

[image]

as you can see there is only a small white part on the device but thats it, noting much is loading after this.

the full code ;

```
package com.example.[removed];

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class WebViewAct extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    WebView mYWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mYWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mYWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mYWeb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mYWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mYWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mYWeb.setScrollBarStyle(0);
    mYWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mYWeb.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mYWeb.loadUrl("http://IP/Filename.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web_view, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

any help will be great!
PS: I found out that it shows the content in Firefox and Chrome even worse, but in chrome, if i swtich to ''Request desktop site everhting works like charm!''
so if possible can i make webView show as Desktop mode as default?

EDIT:

Problem fixed.
I added `mYWeb.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);`and after that i made a String with the following text inside of it: `String ua =  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";`

and everything worked perfect after that!
i maybe asked this quastion too fast, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed. 
`I added mYWeb.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);`and after that i made a String with the following text inside of it: `String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";`

and everything worked perfect after that! 
i maybe asked this quastion too fast, sorry :)